# How to load my module after than other

Tags: magento2, collection, filter

I have a module that print filters, but it loads before that magento catalog, and when I do
 `$activeFilters = $this->_catalogLayer->getState()->getFilters(); $activeFilters is NULL.`

I can load this module after than magento catalog?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare in your `module.xml` file this inside the `<sequence>` tag.  `<Magento_Catalog />`.
But since the order of modules is already built, you need to disable your module from command line and enable it again.